# Neo4j webadmin without Neo4j Server

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I have a neo4j embeeded application implemented with spring Boot .

I have the need to **visualize my graph** and **execute some Cypher query** .

The perfect solution for me is to have the **webadmin interface** deployed somewhere without starting a neo4j server and link the webadmin to my data folder .

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance . 
Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, see this blog post: http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/11/21/neo4j-browser-with-embedded.html

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. You are not able to use Browser app against data folder.

Browser it's not a standalone application you need to have a backend (server) for it. Because it's using REST endpoints of Neo4j server.

Here is the source code - https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3/community/browser

Comment: So I can checkout the browser source and run it from source and change the config to ping my Host Neo4j Embeeded ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your data folder as the project folder in which you have installed and started your neo4j server.

Then probably you can start off making the models and tables associated with Your rest endpoints of Neo4j server.